# De Bruijn sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

There is a rule of building De Bruijn sequences called "$0$ is better than $1$"

How this rule works:

1. Start with $n$ ones
2. Add one at the end of the sequence if and only if by putting zero we get a subsequence which length is $n$ and it has been already written.
3. If there is no way how to produce a new subsequence which length is $n$ - stop.

I need to prove that this algorithm builds De Bruijn sequences correctly. Unfortunately, I could only prove some trivial things like

1. We will never get a repeated sequence
2. We will stop at some point
3. How can I prove that this algorithm will give us every possible subsequence of length $n$?